# smudge in svg animation

Tags: vector, svg, vector-graphics

I'm animating an SVG and notice a smudge or piece of the SVG that shouldn't be there when the browser is done loading. If you check this code pen - http://codepen.io/claire2013/pen/ouIeg you'll notice a little black smudge/drawing on the left side near the nose area of the glasses. Anyone have an idea to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick and Simple Answer**
It looks like you have an extra segment in your path. Search for the following string and delete it:

```
M207.795,61.239l0.097,0.008L207.795,61.239z
```

(Also, there's an extra < at the very beginning of your document.)

See the fixed code here: http://codepen.io/guttentag/pen/JnFzx

**Further Explanation**
In an SVG path, the M command indicates that you want the browser to Move the pen to the coordinates that follow it to start a path. [Other commands](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) follow until you close the path with the Z command.


Since the "smudge" did in fact look like an errant pen stroke on a piece of paper, I tried searching the path for the M character. When I found one that was shortly followed by a Z, I knew that was a segment of the path that didn't belong. I deleted it and the smudge disappeared. If I had deleted the wrong segment, I would just hit undo and try the next likely suspect. Using that technique may help you troubleshoot similar SVG path problems in the future.